# OPTIONS field in Docker CLI commands - diff and cp

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Looking at the Docker CLI documentation, I am trying to figure out what are the different [OPTIONS] possible in the below mentioned commands:

```
docker diff [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH
```

I tried `docker diff --help` to look at the various options possible, but its not very helpful. What are the possible [OPTIONS] in the above command?

My use case is that I want to look at the files/directories added/modified in a Docker container and then export the whole diff directory tree to my local folder. For example:

```
docker diff cedd838b75fe
C /bin
C /bin/lsblk
C /bin/sync
C /bin/tailf
A /blablabla.sh
```

I want to export it to my local directory /tmp/diff. So the /tmp/diff would be:

```
/tmp/diff
      |
      |--bin
      |  |__lsblk
      |  |__sync
      |  |__tailf
      |
      |--blablabla.sh
```

Normal cp command has flag `--parent`, which allows to preserve whole parent directory structure when copying a file(`cp --parent /src/path /dest`).

Is there something inbuilt on similar lines in docker? Any pointers for the same?

Answer (score 0):

As the --help says:

```
docker diff CONTAINER
```

has only the option --help and

```
docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH
```

has the option --help and a second one:

```
-L, --follow-link   Always follow symbol link in SRC_PATH
```